MultiDatabase Relationship Model
My goal is to create a project for multiple vehicle resellers. I need to stay up-to-date with new brands, models, versions, and years that are constantly being released.
However, it’s not practical for me to update all the vehicle sites I manage with the same information repeatedly, as this leads to redundant data, especially when dealing with a large volume of information.
To solve this, my idea was to create a common database to store data that is shared across all sites and needs to be kept up-to-date. The common database contains nested years, versions, models, brands, types tables.
The problem lies in the integration. My main database (and future databases, as there will be multiple, all referring to the common database) stores data about the listed vehicles, including a reference to the year_id of the vehicle, which is stored in the common database.
I’ve already set up a model in my Laravel project as usual, including the BelongsTo relationships. I also specified the connection to be used for the Year, Version, Model, Brand, and Type models.
However, when I try to use a controller, it fails. For example, it tries to search for version.id in the wrong database. I’ve tried a few solutions, but none have worked so far.
PS. I'm considering using an API to communicate to the database in the future so I can implement a cache in the response to minimize the requests to the common database, don't know if it will influence now, I think I can manage changing it later.
Heres a part of the controller:
`    
    public function index()
    {
        $ajustes = Ajustes::first();

        $cars = Vehicles::query()
        ->with(['year.version.model.brand.type'])
        ->status(1)
        ->typeId(1)
        ->orderBy('vehicles.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->limit($ajustes->max_cars ?? 5)
        ->get();
`

Here's a the Vehicle model:
`
<?php
    /**
     * Created by Reliese Model.
     */

    namespace App\Models;

    use App\User;
    use App\Traits\UsesCustomConnection;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

    /**
     * Class Vehicles
     * 
     * @property int $id
     * @property string $slug
     * @property string|null $title
     * @property int $status
     * @property string $year_fab
     * @property int $doors
     * @property string $fuel
     * @property string $condition
     * @property string $color
     * @property string $transmission
     * @property float $mileage
     * @property int $accept_trade
     * @property int $only_owner
     * @property int $consignated
     * @property string|null $plate
     * @property float $price
     * @property float|null $original_price
     * @property string|null $warranty
     * @property string|null $description
     * @property int|null $potency
     * @property int|null $chassi
     * @property int|null $engine_displacement
     * @property int|null $tractions
     * @property int|null $passengers
     * @property string|null $bodywork
     * @property int|null $axes
     * @property int|null $dealership_review
     * @property Carbon $created_at
     * @property Carbon|null $updated_at
     * @property string|null $deleted_at
     * @property int $user_id
     * @property int $year_id
     * @property int $users_id
     * 
     * @property Users $users
     * @property Collection|Transactions[] $transactions
     * @property Collection|VehicleContacts[] $vehicle_contacts
     * @property Collection|VehicleOptionals[] $vehicle_optionals
     * @property Collection|VehiclePhotos[] $vehicle_photos
     *
     * @package App\Models
     */
    class Vehicles extends Model
    {
        // protected $apiConnection = 'vehicles_api_global';
        // protected $mainConnection = 'mysql';
        protected $connection = 'mysql';
        use LogsActivity;
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $table = 'vehicles';

        public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            self::creating(function (self $model) {
                $model->slug = uniqid();
            });

            self::created(function (self $model) {
                $slug = slugifyHelper(
                    $model->year->version->model->brand->name,
                    $model->year->version->model->name,
                    $model->year->version->name,
                    $model->year->name,
                    $model->id,
                    $model->getConnection()->getConfig("schema")
                );

                $model->slug = $slug;
                $model->save();
            });
        }

        protected $casts = [
            'status' => 'int',
            'doors' => 'int',
            'mileage' => 'float',
            'accept_trade' => 'int',
            'only_owner' => 'int',
            'consignated' => 'int',
            'price' => 'float',
            'original_price' => 'float',
            'potency' => 'int',
            'chassi' => 'int',
            'engine_displacement' => 'int',
            'tractions' => 'int',
            'passengers' => 'int',
            'axes' => 'int',
            'dealership_review' => 'int',
            'user_id' => 'int',
            'year_id' => 'int',
            'users_id' => 'int'
        ];

        protected $fillable = [
            'slug',
            'title',
            'status',
            'year_fab',
            'doors',
            'fuel',
            'condition',
            'color',
            'transmission',
            'mileage',
            'accept_trade',
            'only_owner',
            'consignated',
            'plate',
            'price',
            'original_price',
            'warranty',
            'description',
            'potency',
            'chassi',
            'engine_displacement',
            'tractions',
            'passengers',
            'bodywork',
            'axes',
            'dealership_review',
            'user_id',
            'year_id',
            'users_id'
        ];

        public function getThumbPath()
        {
            return "assets/images/vehicle/thumb/$this->image";
        }

        public function getLogNameToUse(string $eventName = ''): string
        {
            return "Imóvel";
        }

        public function photos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\VehiclePhotos', 'vehicle_id')->orderBy('order', 'ASC');
        }

        public function getTitle()
        {
            $typeVehicleSlug = $this->typeVehicle->name;
            // return "{$this->year->version->model->brand->name} {$this->year->version->model->name}";

            $id = $this->id;

            return $typeVehicleSlug . ' ' . $id;
        }

        public function getFrontTitle()
        {
            $typeVehicleSlug = $this->typeVehicle->name;
        }

        public function getCoverImage()
        {
            $image = $this->image;

            if (!empty($image)) {
                return asset('/assets/images/vehicle/thumb/' . $image);
            }

            return null;
        }

        /* SCOPE */

        public function scopeStatus($query, $status = null)
        {
            if (!is_null($status)) {
                if ($status == 0) {
                    $query->where('status',  0);
                } else {
                    $query->where('status',  1);
                }
            }
        }

        public function scopeOrder($query, $order = null)
        {
            if (!is_null($order)) {
                switch ($order) {
                    case 1:
                        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        $query->orderBy('price', 'ASC');
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        $query->orderBy('price', 'DESC');
                        break;

                    default:
                        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public function scopePrice($query, $priceMin = null, $priceMax = null)
        {
            if ($priceMax == 0) {
                $priceMax = null;
            }
            if ($priceMin == 0) {
                $priceMin = null;
            }

            if ((!is_null($priceMin)) && (!is_null($priceMax))) {
                $query->where('price', '>', getFloatFromInput($priceMin));
                $query->where('price', '<', getFloatFromInput($priceMax));
            } else if (!is_null($priceMin)) {
                $query->where('price', '>', getFloatFromInput($priceMin));
            } else if (!is_null($priceMax)) {
                $query->where('price', '<', getFloatFromInput($priceMax));
            }
        }

        public function scopeActive(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, ?bool $value): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->where('active', '=', $value);
            }
        }

        public function scopeJoins($query)
        {
            $query->with([
                'years.versions.models.brands.types',
            ]);
        }

        public function scopeTypeId($query, $typeId)
        {
            if (!is_null($typeId)) {
                $query->whereHas('year.version.model.brand.type', function ($q) use ($typeId) {
                    $q->where('id', $typeId);
                });
            }
        }

        public function scopeBrandId($query, $brandId)
        {
            if (!is_null($brandId)) {
                $query->whereHas('year.version.model.brand', function ($q) use ($brandId) {
                    $q->where('id', $brandId);
                });
            }
        }
        
        public function scopeModelId($query, $modelId)
        {
            if (!is_null($modelId)) {
                $query->whereHas('year.version.model', function ($q) use ($modelId) {
                    $q->where('id', $modelId);
                });
            }
        }
        
        public function scopeVersionId($query, ?int $value): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->whereHas('years.versions', function ($q) use ($value) {
                    $q->where('id', $value);
                });
            }
        }

        public function scopeYearId($query, ?int $value): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->whereHas('years', function ($q) use ($value) {
                    $q->where('id', $value);
                });
            }
        }

        // public function scopeGearId(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, ?int $value): void
        // {
        //     if (!empty($value)) {
        //         $query->where('gear_id', '=', $value);
        //     }
        // }

        public function scopeFuelId(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, ?int $value): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->where('fuel_id', '=', $value);
            }
        }

        /* MUTATORS */

        public function setCodeAttribute(?string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['code'] = empty($value) ? null : $value;
        }

        public function setPriceAttribute(string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['price'] = toFloatHelper($value);
        }

        public function setKmAttribute(string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['km'] = $value === "0" || $value > 0 ? toFloatHelper($value) : null;
        }

        public function setColorAttribute(string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['color'] = strtolower($value);
        }

        public function setCompanyIdAttribute(string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['company_id'] = (int) $value > 0 ? $value : null;
        }

        /* ACCESSORS */

        public function getTitleAttribute(): string
        {
            return "{$this->year->version->model->brand->name} {$this->year->version->model->name}";
        }


        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }

        public function transactions()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Transactions::class, 'offered_vehicle');
        }

        public function vehicle_contacts()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(VehicleContacts::class, 'vehicle_id');
        }

        public function vehicle_optionals()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(VehicleOptionals::class, 'vehicle_id');
        }

        public function vehicle_photos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(VehiclePhotos::class);
        }

        public function year()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Years::class, 'year_id', 'id', 'vehicles_api_global');
        }
        
    }
`

Here's the Year model:
`
<?php
    namespace App\Models;

    /**
     * Created by Reliese Model.
     */

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
    use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

    /**
     * Class Years
     * 
     * @property int $id
     * @property string $name
     * @property int $status
     * @property Carbon $created_at
     * @property Carbon|null $updated_at
     * @property string|null $deleted_at
     * @property int $version_id
     * 
     * @property Versions $versions
     *
     * @package App\Models
     */
    class Years extends Model
    {
        use LogsActivity;
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $connection = 'vehicles_api_global';
        protected $table = 'years';

        protected $casts = [
            'status' => 'int',
            'version_id' => 'int'
        ];

        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'status',
            'version_id'
        ];

        public function version()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Versions::class, 'version_id', 'id');
        }


        /* SCOPES */

        public function scopeName(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, $value): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->where('name', 'ilike', '%' . $value . '%');
            }
        }

        public function scopeVersionId(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query, ?int $value = null): void
        {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                $query->where('version_id', '=', $value);
            }
        }

        /* MUTATORS */

        protected function setCodeAttribute(?string $value): void
        {
            $this->attributes['code'] = empty($value) ? null : $value;
        }
    }
`

The error I get is pretty straightforward, he can't connect to the right database during the query.

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'prestigeauto.years' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from vehicles
where status = 1 and exists (select * from years where
vehicles.year_id = years.id and exists (select * from
versions where years.version_id = versions.id and exists
(select * from models where versions.model_id = models.id
and exists (select * from brands where models.brand_id =
brands.id and exists (select * from types where
brands.type_id = types.id and id = 1 and
types.deleted_at is null) and brands.deleted_at is null) and
models.deleted_at is null) and versions.deleted_at is null)
and years.deleted_at is null) and vehicles.deleted_at is null
order by vehicles.created_at desc limit 4)

I tried to specify the connection in the models, I tried to join them but failed because of the difference in databases.
I tried to do 2 separe querys in the spot, but didn't work either.

"as this leads to redundant data" I'd gladly trade a little redundant data to get a standalone app that didn't need to make a remote connection for basic lookups. We're not talking about that much information here, and disk space is essentially free nowadays. The full CSV dataset of 50K records is under 20 mb uncompressed. That's not worth your time to bother about.

Welcome to StackOverflow, @vítor bg. How did you specify the connection in the model? And how did you specify there are two connections? (I suppose in the .env file and in the config/database.php) Please show some more code about that.

Thank you @JorisJ1, the connection in the model is on the code I posted already.
protected $connection = 'vehicles_api_global';
I manually defined the conenction instead of using the default one, it worked but not completely. Yes I registered the connections on config/database.php and .env files and in the models I simply called them it did work but when I tried to search something the query seemed to kinda die, because it keep mixing the two connections. The query is in the code I posted before. I can't post much more on a comment because of text limit.

@AlexHowansky I kinda understand you but I'll have to maintain this and like I said, this project will be used for multiple websites each one having it's on database, so if I have like 50 sites, I'll monthly need to update each one of them

You can always edit your question and add more information, @vítor. Aside from the connection problem, are you sure with(['year.version.model.brand.type']) is correct? Maybe I am wrong, but I thought it should be with(['year', 'version', 'model', 'brand', 'type']). Also, what do you mean with 'the query seemed to kinda die', is there an error or are you certain the wrong DB is being looked at? Maybe you can show (a part of) your data model? That might help us understand better.

@JorisJ1 I posted the data model, but it was cropped, but sure I can show more. I'll use years since it is the closest to vehicles and the first in the relation chain.
And about the with(['year.version.model.brand.type']) I'm pretty sure it's correct bc, the only model that is directly related to Vehicles model is Years, so I need to get the relationships throught him. I didn't know I could edit the question. I'll try it.

I see, so a Vehicle has a Year which has a Version and so on. And I now see that you want your query to access both databases at once, with Vehicle from the mysql connection and year from the vehicles_api_global connection. Are you sure this is even possible, two databases in 1 query?

@JorisJ1, that's what I'm trying to see, that's why I asked here. In theory it should work to list and show, but to search like I'm doing probably not, but It could work if I used multiple queries, but by doing that it'll probably decrease my perfomance so it wouldn't be good. That's why I considered making an API instead to do the queries and cache the responses, but I think it wouldn't resolve either way. But just in case I threw the problem here to see if anyone had a similar case.

If you are working with two different databases (not just schemas within the same database), you will need to establish two separate connections. This is because SQL queries execute within a single connection, meaning you cannot reference two databases or connections in a single query. Additionally, it's not possible to define foreign keys between two separate databases at the database level.
As a result, you cannot directly define relationships between Eloquent models if their underlying tables reside in separate databases. Instead, you’ll need to handle them independently by running separate queries. Laravel allows you to assign a specific connection to each model.
However, if by "database" you actually mean a different schema within the same server, then it's possible to work across schemas. In this case, you can specify the schema name as part of the table name in your model.
If you're working with two connections, you won’t be able to use Laravel’s built-in relationship features (e.g., hasOne, belongsTo). However, you could still encapsulate the logic within the model by defining custom methods. Example:
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'connection1'; 
}

class Quote extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'connection2'; 

    public function getCarDetails(): ?Car
    {
        return Car::where('model_number', $this->model_number)->first();
    }
}


Thank you for the answer @lbrandao, yeah it was two different databases literally, I already thought I couldn't make it like this but wanted to be sure. But your answer helped me with another problem, so I got something out of this.
